# Error on using glm with SparkR

Tags: r, glm, sparkr

I'm using the following code to run a logistic regression on sparkR :

```
SPARK_HOME <- "C:\\Users\\Softwares\\spark-1.6.0-bin"

Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "C:\\Users\\Softwares\\spark-1.6.0-bin")
Sys.setenv('SPARKR_SUBMIT_ARGS'='"--packages" "com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.2.0" "sparkr-shell"')
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CONF = "C:\\Users\\Softwares\\hadoop-2.6.0\\bin")
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_HOME = "C:\\Users\\Softwares\\hadoop-2.6.0")

.libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib"), .libPaths()))

library(SparkR)

sc <- sparkR.init(master = "local[4]", sparkHome = SPARK_HOME, sparkEnvir = list(spark.driver.memory="512m"))
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)

df1 <- read.df(sqlContext, "flattened-path1.csv", source = "com.databricks.spark.csv")

clogit <- glm(C13 ~ C1+C2+C3+C4+C5+C6+C7+C8+C9+C10
          +C11+C12, data = df1, family = "binomial")
```

And I'm getting the following exception :

```
Error in invokeJava(isStatic = TRUE, className, methodName, ...) : 
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Currently, LogisticRegression with ElasticNet in ML package only supports binary classification. Found 5 in the input dataset.
at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression.train(LogisticRegression.scala:290)
at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression.train(LogisticRegression.scala:159)
at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:71)
at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline$$anonfun$fit$2.apply(Pipeline.scala:144)
at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline$$anonfun$fit$2.apply(Pipeline.scala:140)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
at scala.collection.IterableViewLike$Transformed$class.foreach(IterableViewLike.scala:42)
at scala.collection.SeqViewLike$AbstractTransformed.foreach(SeqViewLike.scala:43)
at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline.fit(Pipeline.scala:140)
```

The target variable C13 is an integer field with 4 unique values. If thats an issue, would converting this field into a factor work or anything else entirely?

**Update**
I tweaked my dataset and removed two unique values so that I'm left with just two values (0 & 1). Surprisingly I got almost the same error message :

```
Currently, LogisticRegression with ElasticNet in ML package only supports binary classification. Found 3 in the input dataset
```

Comment: I would try it in R first and once it works, port it to SparkR.

Comment: So, I've been running the same on R albeit making C13 as factor as following df$C13 <- factor(df1$C13). What i could make out it as that this runs a multinomial regression than a binomial one (correct me if im wrong) and if thats the case, is it not possible in sparkR, thats what i want to confirm

Comment: Just to clarify, when i run it in R, df is a normal data frame as df <- read.csv("xyz.csv") and then the factor transformation

Comment: are there "NA"s in C13? Those could be your third value. If they are there, the field will be inferred as a string with 3 values.

Comment: @xyxxy : No NA's in the data. As I mentioned in my edit, I also tried it out with keeping just two values in C13 (0 & 1), still faced the same issue